# Looping sql statement return so slow

Tags: mysql

first, I make select statement in another function.

From that another function, I get some fields from my table in database in which one of them is for instance a field of `variable`.

From that sql statment I got 10000 rows or more.

I take that field of `variable` to make a sql statement again.

```
    $variable = (10000 values here)
```

And then I tried to do sql select statement based on the value:

```
$sql = $this->db->query

    ("   
        SELECT logintime FROM game_login WHERE data_id = '".$variable ."'

    ");
```

In another words, it meant that I do 10000 select statements.

And it makes my query so slowssss.

How to fix this so that the query run fast?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql Server? they are 2 different things. 
Use a single statement with a join expression instead of a 10000 times loop.

Comment: I don't use join because the are some of the result which are not exist in the join and it will cut of the number of rows.

Comment: then use left / right join.

Comment: I have tried left/right join, and the number of result is different if I don't use join at all.

Comment: Then find some other way of returning the all of the records in a single query. if it's sql server you can use a table valued parameter. for MySql I don't know if something similar exists.

Comment: my answer should work, have you tried it @iyal

Answer (score 1):

Make the long variable a comma seperated list...

Then do this ...

```
 SELECT logintime FROM game_login WHERE data_id IN ('$myvariable')
```

***If  your variable is an array do this to make it a comma separated string.***

```
    $myvariable = '';
    foreach $variable as $v) {
        $myvariable .= $v.',';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make a comma seperated string for IN() paramater using implode() function of PHP. Like:

```
 $instr = implode(",",$variable);
```

Now You can use the IN() for the 10000 values. Like:

```
 SELECT logintime FROM game_login WHERE data_id IN ('$instr')
```